# Remove computer asset from Active Directory and SCCM 2012 - Powershell

Tags: powershell, sccm

I am trying to modify the following script to allow me to:-

1. Read from a list of computers in a csv
2. Delete each computer from Activedirectory & SCCM 2012

I have very limited powershell experience, so any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks Adi

```
# Environment setup 
# Import the ActiveDirectory module to enable the Get-ADComputer CmdLet 
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$sccmServer = SCCMServer
$sccmSite = Site
$computerName = Import-CSV -Path Assets.csv

# find and delete the computer from AD
ForEach ($pc in $computers) {
$dom = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()
$root = $dom.GetDirectoryEntry()
$search = [System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher]$root
$search.filter = "(&(objectclass=computer)(name=$computerName))"
$search.findall() | %{$_.GetDirectoryEntry() } | %{$_.DeleteObject(0)}

# find and delete from SCCM
$comp = get-wmiobject -query "select * from SMS_R_SYSTEM WHERE Name='$computerName'" -computername $sccmServer -namespace "ROOT\SMS\site_$sccmSite"
$comp.psbase.delete()
 }
# spit out results
Write-Host "Deleted $computerName from AD. Removed $computerName from SCCM server $sccmServer, site $sccmSite"
```

Comment: What is the question? Is something you are doing not working? I would also suggest using `Remove-ADComputer` since you are using the activedirectory module.

Comment: I have added the following but i am unsure if this script is in the right format? # Environment setup 
# Import the ActiveDirectory module to enable the Get-ADComputer CmdLet 
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$sccmServer = SCCMServer
$sccmSite = Site
$computerName = Import-CSV -Path Assets.csv

Comment: SCCMServer : The term 'SCCMServer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, At C:\temp\Powershell\Delete_from_AD_&_SCCM\DelComp-ADSccm.ps1:5 char:15
+ $sccmServer = SCCMServer
+               ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SCCMServer:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: What is the hostname of your SCCM Server? Change the line `$sccmServer = SCCMServer` and see if that helps. I do not have access to an SCCM infrastructure to test.

Comment: I have changed the name for this public post, i get the error with the correct sccm server etc